# Refsection always resets counter

Tags: biblatex, biber

For some reason, the following code always assigns to both references the number [1] in the two bibliographies. From the biblatex manual, I would assume that the default behaviour would be consecutive numbering and that the flag

```
resetnumbers=false
```

would be required. However, for some reason, resetting the numbers seems to be the default here and I cannot find a way to switch it off.

Also, if I replace

```
\newrefsection
```

with

```
\newrefsegment
```

than both references appear in *both* bibliographies. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{test1,
        author={Author A},
        title={Test},
        journal={Test},
        year={2016},
}

@article{test2,
        author={Author B},
        title={Test},
        journal={Test},
        year={2016},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section One}
Here is one reference~\cite{test1}
\printbibliography

\newrefsection

\section*{Section Two}
Here is a second reference~\cite{test2}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing everything from section to segments should work if you put the `\printbibliography` commands outside the segments, which you have to explicitly delimit with `\begin{refsegment} … \end{refsegment}`. You also have to manually define which segment to print with which print command.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

   \usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
   \addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section One}

\begin{refsegment}
    Here is one reference~\cite{test1}
\end{refsegment}

\printbibliography[segment=1]

\section*{Section Two}

\begin{refsegment}
    Here is a second reference~\cite{test2}
\end{refsegment}
\printbibliography[segment=2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you use `segment=\therefsegment` you can get the bibliography of the currently active segment without mentioning it explicitly. You will then have to move the `\printbibliography` to before the `\end{refsegment}`, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Nice, that works, too. Obviously, the crucial missing part in my example above was the explicit reference to a segment in `\printbibliography`.